# Why does this HQL delete fail, when an HQL select with same terms works?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, hql, ora-00933, hql-delete

Why does the following HQL query fail?

```
string hql = @"delete MyLog log
               where
                    log.UtcTimestamp < :threshold and
                    log.Configuration.Application = :application";

session.CreateQuery(hql)
       .SetDateTime("threshold", threshold)
       .SetEnum("application", this.application)
       .ExecuteUpdate();
```

The same form of query works when used in a select:

```
string hql = @"from MyLog log
               where
                    log.UtcTimestamp < :threshold and
                    log.Configuration.Application = :application";
IList<MyLog> log = session.CreateQuery(hql)
    .SetDateTime("threshold", threshold)
    .SetEnum("application", this.application)
    .List<MyLog>();
```

The mapping for MyLog contains:

```
References(x => x.Configuration)
     .Columns("CONFIGURATION_ID")
     .ReadOnly();
```

The mapping for Configuration contains:

```
Map(x => x.Application, "APPLICATION_ID");
```

The error I get is:

> delete from MYLOG, CONFIGURATION
>   countercon1_ where UTC_TIMESTAMP<:p0
>   and APPLICATION_ID=:p1; :p0 =
>   04/10/2010 17:15:52, :p1 = 7
>
> NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException:
>   could not execute update query [SQL:
>
> delete from MYLOG, CONFIGURATION
>   countercon1_ where UTC_TIMESTAMP< ? and
>   APPLICATION_ID= ?
>
> ] --->
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException:
>   ORA-00933: SQL command not properly
>   ended

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct

Comment: Can you try http://www.codepaste.net/nmrne1 ? Or perhaps http://www.codepaste.net/q5m8on ? It would also rock if you used http://nhprof.com/

Comment: + 1.  Thanks Fafael.  It looks like the problem might be: 'No joins, either implicit or explicit, can be specified in a bulk HQL query. Sub-queries can be used in the where-clause, where the subqueries themselves may contain joins.'

Comment: Thanks for the code examples. I've tried both but I believe the implicit join is causing the problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
delete MyLog log
where log.id in
          (select l.id
           from MyLog l
           where l.UtcTimestamp < :threshold and
           and.Configuration.Application = :application)
```

Comment: Just came back to this problem and your answer worked first time :)

Answer (score 3):

From the link submitted by Rafael above:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct

> No joins, either implicit or explicit,
>   can be specified in a bulk HQL query.
>   Sub-queries can be used in the
>   where-clause, where the subqueries
>   themselves may contain joins

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is `DELETE FROM MyLog ....`

Have in mind that HQL delete does not honour cascades defined with (n)hibernate mappings.

So you can select all the entities and delete them one by one.

Comment: @Thomas The FROM is indeed optional when using [DML-style operations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct).