# NHibernate expand composite id from HQL

Tags: nhibernate, hql, composite-primary-key

We have a table with a composite primary key mapped, as shown below:

```
mapping.CompositeId().KeyReference(e => e.Node).KeyProperty(e => e.DtFr).UnsavedValue("any");
```

We need to delete several rows from the table by complex condition, for example `n.Node.Contract.Code = "1234"`

According to the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863309/why-does-this-hql-delete-fail-when-an-hql-select-with-same-terms-works) we tried next HQL:

```
delete from Entity n where n in (select c from Entity c where c.Node.Contract.Code = "1234")
```

But in the generated SQL-query there are no parentheses around the primary key columns:

```
select ... from ENTITY n where n.IDNODE, n.DTFR in (select c.IDNODE, c.DTFR ...
```

We tried explicitly to add parentheses in HQL (`where (n) in`), but NHibernate ignores them.

**What can we do to make NHibernate generate the correct SQL?**

Version of NHibernate is `4.1.1.4000`, RDBMS is `Oracle 10.2`.

SQL dialect is set to `NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect`.

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely there is a bug in NHibernate. Issue is added: https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/1376.

So for now the only solution is: load all the entities you want to delete and then delete them.

```
var entities2delete = session.CreateQuery("select c from Entity c where c.Node.Contract.Code = \"1234\"").List();
foreach (var item in entities2delete) session.Delete(item);
```